# Is there any difference between setting up a host by A record and by CNAME?

Tags: networking, dns, cname

To create a www host, should I use A record, i.e.,

[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) => ip xx.xx.xx.xx

, or use both A record and CNAME, i.e,

mydomain.com => ip xx.xx.xx.xx

www => mydomain.com

If both methods have the same effect, i.e., resolve to the same ip, do they have different influence on SEO?

ps: I've already created A record for the naked domain mydomain.com. I just want users who type [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) can also enter the same web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'A' record is an address record. It is required to map a DNS name to an IP address. In most configurations, your naked domain (example.com) is pointed to a web server using an A record.

The 'CNAME' record is a Canonical Name record. The CNAME identifies the canonical name of an alias. In other words, this allows you to map a domain or subdomain to another one.

You can map subdomains (www, mail, etc), to IP addresses as well, to send that traffic to a different server. However, most standard website configurations will use a CNAME record to alias those subdomains to the same server as the A record. This allows you to change the webserver IP address, and only have to update it one time in DNS, on your A record.

Then your webserver configuration determines what to do with traffic it receives. You can configure it to treat subdomains with special rules, all on the same webserver and IP address.

So the A record is absolutely required in order for DNS to resolve a domain name to an IP address. The CNAME records are not required, but commonly used to map www subdomain to your webserver as well as the naked domain.

Example DNS entries:

A Record - example.com - 123.45.6.789

CNAME Record - [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) - example.com.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)

And to answer your question regarding SEO, you want to setup your records like I show here, but you should pick one way for clients to access your website. Either with, or without the www. You should have the naked domain entry, AND the www entry, to ensure that any users that type either domain into their browser will get routed to the website. However, you should pick one way, and then stick with one way. Either present your site as https://example.com, or https://www.example.com, but not both. Use .htaccess file to force all incoming requests to rewrite the domain with or without the www. For SEO, as much as possible, you only want a single authoritative URL for each webpage. This will help ensure search engines see you as one site, and not two.

Comment: You might want to modify your answer - a CNAME is not the same thing as an ALIAS. An alias is a construct (ie not a record type recognized by the DNS standard).  Basically a nameserver works out how to convert a domain name alias into an IP record and returns an A record - ie the nameserver does the resolution.  A CNAME is a record type that is returned by the nameserver so the client does the resolution.

Comment: CNAME is not an alias, and I edited my answer accordingly. In RFC 1034, 3.6.2, the section is titled Aliases and Canonical Names. CNAME is inextricably linked to aliases, which is just another name for a particular resource. While "alias" is not a DNS record type, it is very much a part of DNS. A CNAME (canonical name) for a resource in one zone, might be an alias in a different zone. You configure an alias with a CNAME record (dns entry type) to map to a CNAME (canonical name). Terminology can be confusing when  the same name for a record type is used for what that record is referencing.

Answer (score 3):

CNAMES and A records serve entirely different purposes.

If you are in doubt, and if you have control of the ultimate IP address the domain/subdomain will go to, use an A record. I say this for 2 reasons -

- CNAMES are commonly misunderstood, and have hidden gotchas, because they do more then allow a subdomain to another domain (they actually modify the way all lower level subdomains, and other resource records resolve). If you must use a CNAME, and are not an expert, only use a CNAME on a subdomain - ie its likely OK for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) but not for example.com
- CNAMES are inefficient. They require an additional DNS lookup.

(By contrast, A records are simple and intuitive)

No one who has not signed an NDA with the search engine company can authoratively advise if a CNAME will impact SEO. Id say this is highly unlikely but if there is a penalty it is going to be vanishingly small, to the point if being almost irrelevant. CNAMES are ubiquitous.  My **guess** is that CNAMES are not factored in to googles algorithms, except possibly as an influence on time to first byte, which would be longer due to the additional lookup.

Answer (score 0):

In simple word I can say: An A record points a name to an IP . A CNAME record can point a name to another CNAME or to an A record.